# Insert a list of data using Entity Framework Model

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

To add a new record to the database I usually use `context.TableName.Add(TableEntityInstance);`. When I add multiple records for the same table I usually iterate through the list using a `foreach` loop. `foreach (var item in list) { context.TableName.Add(item); }` It is possible to add the entire list to the database in one go. Such as: `context.TableName.Add(list);` Just wondering if this was possible. If so what are there any pros or cons to this approach?

Comment: `context.TableName.Add` itself does not commit anything to the database just yet, that happens when you call `SaveChangesAsync`. So in that regard, the difference between adding multiple items in a foreach loop and adding them all in one go is neglible. To answer your question though, [`DbSet<T>` has a method `AddRangeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.addrange) to which you can pass an `IEnumerable<T>` (list) of items to add them all in one go.

Comment: I have found that if I do list.ForEach(item => context.TableName.Add(item)) this works too. Is this bad in any way?

Comment: @Imogen repeated Add, could lead to multiple round trips to the database. See the below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77885571/479251) .  I'd recommend checking the DB queries generated i the debug console.

Comment: @Pac0 the answer is incorrect. `SaveChangesAsync` causes roundtrips, not `Add`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method called `.AddRange()` or  `.AddRangeAsync()` which is used for adding a list of items to a context.

One drawback is if one of the items already exists on the database, the whole method call will fail.

Comment: _"With your previous loop, every single .Add() call leads to a database round-trip."_ - no, it does not (at least "by default"). `SaveChanges(Async)` is what causes roundtrip to the database. And there is no difference between `AddRange` and `Add` approaches in terms of failure or success of the insertion if `SaveChanges(Async)` is called once (after everything is added to the context).

Comment: @GuruStron You are right. i have updated my answer to reflect this. ty